# how we can encode and decode the image string data and show on imageview

Tags: android

i am getting the decoded string data of image and i want to encode that data and show on image view. i getting the null value in bitmap.

that is what i have done so far.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void show(View view){ 
     byte[] imageBytes = null;
    try {
        imageBytes = imagedata.getBytes("UTF-8");
    break;
// here you could place handling of other clicks if necessary...        
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
         image.setImageBitmap(b);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to decode an image use the following code:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image_path, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length, options);
// options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
promoIV.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```